# How do I lower enemy health in a Dungeon Siege LAN game? (Without lowering difficulty.)

Tags: dungeon-siege

Recent I was playing a LAN game of the original Dungeon Siege with a group of 8 people. (maximum party size for the game) Some of the basic bad guys had upwards of 700 health, and as we progressed in the game, we were getting to guys with more than 3,000-4,000 health, and they took forever to kill.

Is there a way to lower the health of the monsters?  I realize that each added character in multiplayer adds health to the monsters, but 4,000 health on some of those guys really turns the game into a grind. (You know the enemies have too much life when you get your guy to fight one, go make a sandwich, eat it while you watch your guy hammer away...)

Is there a way to lower the monster health and increase their number or something instead?  (I would be happy with an answer that just helped me make them weaker.)  Lowering the difficulty seems to lower the treasure and XP values so much that you never find any good items, and never level up.  Plus the bad guys don't do as much damage either, so it goes back to being more of a grinder...)

Comment: (Assuming DS1) I would cast my eyes around for a mod to adjust this. Somewhere like http://www.siegenetwork.com/index.php Although you might struggle as the game was officially de-supported in 2006.